# How do I add nested JSON-LD Schema entities in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, schema, advanced-custom-fields, json-ld

Rather than using a plug-in I am in the process of creating my own schema markup for a home page on a WordPress site which makes use of Advananced Custom Fields (ACF) for some of the content relevant to this challenge. My aim is to give me a little more granular control over what is output and as a little personal challenge :)

So far I have successfully created a basic schema, but I have become stuck where I need to create a nested entity for a list of services.

currently I have this in my functions.php file:

```
function schema() {
    $schema = array(
        '@context'  => "http://schema.org",
        '@type'     => "ProfessionalService",
        'name'      => get_bloginfo('name'),
        'url'       => get_home_url(),
        // ... and so on 
    );

    if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
        $schema['itemListElement'] = array();
        while (have_rows('services_list')) : the_row();
        $services = array(
            '@type'       => 'Offer',
            'itemOffered' => array (
                '@type'     => 'Service',
                'name'      => get_sub_field('service')
            )
        );
        array_push($schema['itemListElement'], $services);
        endwhile;
    }        
    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema) . '</script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'schema');
```

Result:

```
{
    "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type":"ProfessionalService",
    "name":"Name of Company",
    "url":"http:\/\/www.whatever.com",
    and so on...
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type":"Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
                "@type":"Service", 
                "name":"Service One"
            }
        },
        { 
            "@type":"Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
                "@type":"Service",
                "name":"Service Two"
            }
        },
        ... more services
    ]
}
```

This resulting markup is great, but I need to nest the itemListElement so that it outputs like so:

```
"hasOfferCatalog": {
    "@type": "OfferCatalog",
    "name": "Some Services",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type":"Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
                "@type":"Service", 
                "name":"Service One"
            }
        },
        { 
            "@type":"Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
                "@type":"Service",
                "name":"Service Two"
            }
        },
        ... more services
```

I can't for the life of me work out how this is done. My current best effort is to add it like so:

```
if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
    'hasOfferCatalog'   => array(
        '@type'     => 'OfferCatalog',
        'name'      => 'Tree Surgery'
        $schema['itemListElement'] = array();
        while (have_rows('services_list')) : the_row();
        $services = array(
            '@type'       => 'Offer',
            'itemOffered' => array (
                '@type'     => 'Service',
                'name'      => get_sub_field('service')
            )
        );
        array_push($schema['itemListElement'], $services);
        endwhile;
    )
}
```

However this is not working at all. If anyone can point me in the right direction to the nested entities working in this context I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently trying to do exactly the same, for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: @TraceDeCoy Unfortuntely this project was put to sleep for a while, so I never got to look too much further into it. However in a subsequent project I have taken a different approach and set the script up as part of the page itself rather than trying to do it though the functions file. This page has different content and therefore he schema is different, but I'll have a fiddle and see if that can be applied here.

Comment: @TraceDeCoy Ignore what I said above. I was thinking of a totally dofferent project :). Its such  long time since I did this I had completely forgotten. I did solve it and have posted my solution below.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for sharing below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually manage to solve my issue. I never got around to posting this at he time, but since here's been a little interest here's what I did.

My 'best effort' was almost there, but I needed to make a few small adjustments. Sadly I sorted this out sometime ago and I forget the resource I used to put things right, but I hope this might be of help to someone else.

```
if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
    $schema['hasOfferCatalog'] = array();
    $catalog = array(
        '@type'     => 'OfferCatalog',
        'name'      => 'Tree Surgery'
    );
    if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
        $catalog['itemListElement'] = array();
        while (have_rows('services_list')) : the_row();
        $services = array(
            '@type'       => 'Offer',
            'itemOffered' => array (
                '@type'     => 'Service',
                'name'      => get_sub_field('service')
            )
        );
        array_push($catalog['itemListElement'], $services);
        endwhile;
        array_push($schema['hasOfferCatalog'], $catalog);
    }
}
```

Fr a little bit of context I have this all placed in my functions.php file and is put together like so:

```
function schema() {
    $schema = array(
        '@context'  => "http://schema.org",
        '@type'     => "ProfessionalService",
        'name'      => get_bloginfo('name'),
        'url'       => get_home_url(),
        'telephone' => '+00 0000 00000',
        'address'   => array(
            '@type'           => 'PostalAddress',
            'streetAddress'   => 'XXXXX',
            'postalCode'      => 'XXX XXX',
            'addressLocality' => 'XXXXXX',
            'addressRegion'   => 'XXXXXXX',
            'addressCountry'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
        ),
        'logo'      => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/image.svg',
        'image'     => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/image.svg'
    );

    if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
        $schema['hasOfferCatalog'] = array();
        $catalog = array(
            '@type'     => 'OfferCatalog',
            'name'      => 'Tree Surgery'
        );
        if ( have_rows('services_list') ) {
            $catalog['itemListElement'] = array();
            while (have_rows('services_list')) : the_row();
            $services = array(
                '@type'       => 'Offer',
                'itemOffered' => array (
                    '@type'     => 'Service',
                    'name'      => get_sub_field('service')
                )
            );
            array_push($catalog['itemListElement'], $services);
            endwhile;
            array_push($schema['hasOfferCatalog'], $catalog);
        }
    }    
    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema) . '</script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'schema');
```

It seems to do the job.